# How does one check the meaning of a numerical return value in C under Linux?

Tags: c, linux, error-handling

Suppose I'm invoking write() and it returns with the error -8. How can I check which one of the documented error return values this stands for?

Answer (score 4):

You'd usually use

```
  man functionname
```

or perhaps

```
  man -S2 functionname # specify other section (2, 3, 5, 7)
```

Most functions that return 0 on success, nonnull on failure, document that they also set `errno`. You can get the meaning of the `errno` *global variable*<sup>1</sup>

- by looking at `errno.h`
- by using the `strerror` function (`#include <string.h>`)
- or use the convenient helper `perror` that prints an error message based on `strerror` and the prefix given:

  ```
   perror("oops, popen failed with: ");
  ```

<sub><sup>1</sup> well, it doesn't technically need to be a global variable. Depending on your OS/library it may be a macro, a threadlocal variable, both etc...</sub>

Comment: The actual definitions are in: `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h` and `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h` - dragged in by `errno.h` of course.

Comment: `perror` worth mentioning, but it goes beyond checking and finding out :)

Comment: @sehe, not when the question is tagged 'linux'.

Comment: @BrettHale: Huh? It still depends on platform, even if the question were tagged [tag:brazen-unicorns] :)

Comment: @ Vlad Lazarenko: `perror` adds the colon.  If you put one in your paramter like that you'll have two in the actual output. `oops, popen failed with: :SOME_ERROR`

Answer (score 2):

Look up the [`strerror`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/strerror.3.html) manpage. (note, though that `write()` should only return at worst `-1` and the error code in `errno`).

Answer (score 0):

Formally it is not returning -8, but an error code. These error codes can be found in the manual (e.g. here: http://linux.die.net/man/2/write), and you should use these codes to verify if everything went OK.

so, you would use:

```
 write(..);
if( errno == EFAULT ) { ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

try "[strerror](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror)" and "[errno](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno)".

Answer (score 0):

You should not print out the return value itself, but `strerror(return_value)`. You can also look at `man errno` for error description.